# WSO2 Store : Swagger UI / API Test is using wrong IP

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am setting up a WSO2 docker. I am using the WSO2 Dockerfiles from github (https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim) an the latest WSO2 Api Manager version (2.10). The Installation has succeeded, so I started the docker container. WSO2 starts up and I was able to deploy a Swagger URL based API.

I am also able to access the API through the store interface. And here starts my trouble: When I am trying to test the API through the integrated Swagger UI, the API manager is making use of the internal docker IP:

[image]

I have set up this port configuration:

[image]

How can I force WSO2 Api Manager to use the Docker public IP?

Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the repository/conf/api-manager.xml you can find following element

`APIGateway/Environments/Environment/GatewayEndpoint`

If you have multiple gateways, you may want to create an HTTP(S) load balancer.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your help. I set the value to the matching address, but I still run into the internal container ip. Is there some other location I must edit?

Comment: I double checked the IP  and wso2 seems to try to use the rancher.local.ip - I am using rancher for managing the docker instances. any idea?

Comment: just to finish this thread: replace all host-references with the target host name except the thrift server name does the job very well. and very important: I diligently had to take care about the keystore (cert, chain etc). then it works fine.